# How to program the "Restore Defaults" and "Apply" button in PropertyPages

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am designing a property page for an Eclipse plugin. I need to program the "Restore Default" and "Apply" button that are created by default on the page. Can someone help me with how I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually there is no extra work required to habe apply and restore defaults working. Can you provide a sample of what you intend to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `performDefaults` and `performApply` methods in your property page to handles these buttons. Normally you should call the `super` methods:

```
@Override
protected void performDefaults() {
    super.performDefaults();

    // TODO your code
}

@Override
protected void performApply() {
    super.performApply();

    // TODO your code
}
```